# What is the proper date format for the document?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, puppeteer

I'm having trouble sorting my records with a timestamp field which contains data in the following form: `"Thursday, September 13, 2018 10:01 AM"`.
I suspect there's a proper date & time format I should use so the MongoDB will treat it properly.

I'm generating the data like this: `let timeStamp = moment().format('LLLL');`

Comment: Mongodb stores typed data. The available types are listed in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/. Your "timestamp" is a string and is being sorted as such. To sort by date/time use "Date" type. Inserting from nodejs you can pass a Date object to the driver.

Comment: Thank you, @AlexBlex. That's the thing, surely!

Comment: var myobj = {time: { $type : 9 } timeStamp, ... }
I'm struggling to set the field type, please help.

Comment: You don't specify type in the query but insert javascript objects of correct type. https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson should be used for exotic types like Decimal128 etc, and for date it is a plain javascript [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). Sorry I can't put it simpler than in the last sentence of my previous comment.